# Ant Design Upload full parent width

Tags: antd

How do I get a `<Upload>` to fill parent width ( like block attribute in `<Button>` )?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to solve the same problem: add this:

```
div.ant-upload{
    width: 100%;
}
```

to your CSS with that page.